# How to show recent post of custom category using WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on WordPress site and facing a problem with custom wp_query, as I am using tax_query here. I want to show posts with specific term of some taxonomy. It show perfect result but shows older post. I just want to show latest post with this category. How is it possible? Is there any parameter for order ,or done by some code. Here is my query code structure:

```
$category = $attr['category_slug'];        
$args=array( 'post_type'        =>'post',
                     'posts_per_page'   =>'1',
                     'post_status'      =>'publish',
                     'tax_query'        => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                            'field'    => 'slug',
                                            'terms'    => explode(",",$category),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                );

      $query  = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are not using "order" parameter it will take "DESC" as default for ASCENDING order you have to mention

```
'order' => 'ASC',
```

Now code should be like this for Descending order:

```
$category = $attr['category_slug'];        
$args=array( 'post_type'        =>'post',
                     'posts_per_page'   =>'1',
                     'post_status'      =>'publish',
                     'order'            => 'DESC',
                     'tax_query'        => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                            'field'    => 'slug',
                                            'terms'    => explode(",",$category),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                );

      $query  = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit :)

Answer (score 2):

Following the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters):

```
$category = $attr['category_slug'];        
$args=array( 'post_type'        =>'post',
                     'posts_per_page'   =>'1',
                     'post_status'      =>'publish',
                     'orderby' => 'date',
                     'order'   => 'DESC',
                     'tax_query'        => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                            'field'    => 'slug',
                                            'terms'    => explode(",",$category),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                );

      $query  = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Yea I found the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add 'order' => 'DESC' to display latest post.

```
$category = $attr['category_slug'];        
$args=array( 'post_type'        =>'post',
                     'posts_per_page'   =>'1',
                     'post_status'      =>'publish',
                     'order' => 'DESC',
                     'tax_query'        => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                            'field'    => 'slug',
                                            'terms'    => explode(",",$category),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                );

      $query  = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use order and orderby options according documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        =>'post',
    'posts_per_page'   =>'1',
    'post_status'      =>'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query'        => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => explode(",",$category),
           ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: yes didn't used any parameter , because it's taking "order" field value by default as "DESC", but it doesn't work for me . I tried alot of times. After this I set it's value then it's work fine.